# Android API 20 or Lower Change Spinner Underline color programatically

Tags: android, android-spinner

My question is different to the question above.

I am using a appcompat theme for my application, and using setBackgroundTintList() to set a spinner underline color and it works. However, [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat#setbackgroundtintlist) says This will always take effect when running on API v21 or newer. I would really appreciate if anyone knows how I can change underline color API v20 and lower.

I cannot use styles.xml as I need to change the color depending on some conditions, so I would like to figure out how I can change it dynamically in code.

**Update**
Ok, so now I can change triangle icon color on Android API 20 by changing from Spinner to AppCompatSpinner and using ViewCompat.SetBackgroundTintList().  Reading the document, the spinner needs to implement TintableBackgroundView for API 20 or lower. AppCompatSpinner is implementing TintableBackgroundView.
However, I still cannot see underline :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOU CAN USE THE XML AS A BACKGROUND SO THE BACKGROUND WILL APPEAR IN AL THE API VERSIONS. MAKE YOUR CUSTOM XML LAYOUT FOR SPINNER. EXAMPLE IS

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item>
    <layer-list>
       <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/white" />
                <stroke android:width="2px" android:color="@color/darkgray_7" />
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            </shape>
       </item>

       <item>
            <bitmap
                android:gravity="right" android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
       </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>

</selector>
```

Comment: Thank you!!  I added my background resource file in Drawable folder, and used _spinner.SetBackgroundResource() to set it then, used spinner.SetSupportBackgroundTintList to whatever color I want to set.
My background file contains just
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <layer-list>
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha" />
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha" />
    </layer-list>
  </item>
</selector>

Comment: sorry, cannot edit my comment above anymore.. so, what I wanted to write after the first comment is...
These items are coming from a default material resource folder, which are used by Android 5 and above by default for AppCompat theme. 
Now all android versions change the underline color dynamically. :)